# What is the conditional test in bash to determine if a variabl $f is a directory?

Tags: bash

So I'm scanning through a directory and want to test if each element of the directory is a directory:

```
FILES=$PWD/*

for f in $FILES 
do
  if [ $f is a directory ]; then #Correct conditional needed here
    echo "Dir: $f"
  fi       

done
```

What method/function do I use to test if $f is a directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `-d` to check:

```
if [ -d "$f" ]; then
```